# I have a question about bison conflicts: reduce/reduce

Tags: bison

I have a question about bison reduce/reduce:

```
    ArrayObjectInitializer
        : '{' '}'
        | '{' ArrayInitializer '}'
        ;
    JsonObjectInitializer
        : '{' '}'
        | '{' JsonInitializer '}'
        ;
```

output file:
State 242 conflicts: 2 reduce/reduce

```
   ArrayInitializer: '{' '}'
   JsonInitializer: '{' '}'
```

How can I solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that problem by making sure that there is no context in which both `ArrayObjectInitializer` and `JsonObjectInitializer` are possible.

It's really impossible to know what you are doing if you don't provide a full grammar. Perhaps you missed the fact that JSON arrays are written inside of square brackets (`[` and `]`), not braces (`{` and `}`).

Comment: I may not describe it clearly.It's json object initializer,not json array initializer

Comment: When i write my own script,Both types will be exist at the same time

Comment: @jeffrey: if you can't find the words, share your code. It's best to provide a [mcve].